How to handle late events using Flink's table API?
It looks like Flink's Table API currently drop late events. I've seen some examples leveraging the DataStreaming API, but my entire Flink application uses the Table API, so I am trying to find a way to handle late events using the latter. I've found this approach from 3 years ago, but I am not sure it works anymore.

I was able to dump all late events to a sink using the Table API with the second link in the post:
INSERT INTO lateEventsTable 
    SELECT * 
    FROM sourcedEventsTable
    WHERE CURRENT_WATERMARK(eventTime) IS NOT NULL
        AND eventTime <= CURRENT_WATERMARK(eventTime)

If you want to be able to do more with late events you will need to use the DataStream API (AFAIK).

You want to be careful to the do the normal and late event processing together in a statement set, as shown in the original example -- unless you are doing per-event watermarking. Otherwise watermark generation is non-deterministic, and running the two pipelines independently is likely to produce inconsistent results.

Thanks David! You're right, I left the experiment running overnight and found those inconsistencies myself when I checked the results in the morning. Adding a non-late event clause to the main query within the statement set fixed the problem.
